# $G$ open connect subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f: G \to \Bbb C$ analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

1. $G$ open connect subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f: G \to \Bbb C$ analytic.
2. Suppose $\exists a \in G$ such that $|f(a)| \leq |f(z)|$ for all $z \in G$.

> Prove that either $f(a) = 0$ or $f$ is nonzero constant in $G$.

Suppose $f(a) \not = 0$ and $f$ is not a non zero constant function on $G$.

I just need a hint then I think I should be able to finish the problem.

Comment: Assume $f$ is a non-constant function and show that the minimum in absolute value, if attained in $G$, should be zero.

Comment: There is only a forward implication here. You just need to prove that if $f(z) \neq 0$ on $G$, then $f$ is a non zero constant. Since $f$ is analytic on $G$, it is an open map. Hence $\{|f(z)|\}_{z \in G}$ is an open interval.

Comment: I did not mean to use the terms forward and backward implication. I made an appropriate edit. TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  use the maximum modulus principle or open mapping theorem.

**Solution:** Recall that $f(z)$ is an open mapping unless it is constant (by the open mapping theorem). This implies that a non-constant mapping maps $G$ to an open subset of $\Bbb C$, and $|\cdot |$ maps this to an open subset of $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ (this is how one proves the maximum modulus principle). Since $G$ is connected, $f(G)$ is also connected, hence $f(G)=(c,d)$ or $[0,b)$ for some $0<c<d\in\Bbb R$ or $0<b\in\Bbb R$ since these are the only open subsets of $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$. In the case $f(G)=(c,d)$ there is no minimum, so since we assumed $f$ has one and is non-constant, it must be that $f(G)=[0,b)$, i.e. the minimum is $0$.

If you already know the maximum modulus principle then note that if $|f|>0$ then ${1\over f}$ achieves a maximum, hence $f$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Fry Yes, I included that for others who might search for this topic in the future to learn. You don't have to read it, I left the basic hint at the top for your original request.

Comment: Are you using the subspace topology to have $[0,b)$ open?

Comment: @Mr.Fry Yes! That's right.

Answer (score 0):

The things you say for both directions aren't really sensible.

First note that there is obviously no problem with $f$ being constant.  So that deals with that case.

Now suppose that $f$ is not a constant and that $f(a)\neq 0$.  Derive a contradiction.